# refactor this ruby database/sequel gem lookup

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I know this code is not optimal, any ideas on how to improve it?

```
job_and_cost_code_found = false
  timberline_db['SELECT Job, Cost_Code FROM [JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE] WHERE [Job] = ? AND [Cost_Code] = ?', job, clean_cost_code].each do |row|
    job_and_cost_code_found = true
  end

if job_and_cost_code_found == false then 
  info = linenum + "," + id + ",,Employees default job and cost code do not exist in timberline. job:#{job} cost code:#{clean_cost_code}"
  add_to_exception_output_file(info)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're breaking a lot of simple rules here.

**Don't select what you don't use.**

You select a number of columns, then completely ignore the result data. What you probably want is a count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cost_code_count FROM [JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE] WHERE [Job] = ? AND [Cost_Code] = ?'
```

Then you'll get one `row` that will have either a zero or non-zero value in it. Save this into a variable like:

```
job_and_cost_codes_found = timberline_db[...][0]['cost_code_count']
```

**Don't compare against `false` unless you need to differentiate between that and `nil`**

In Ruby only two things evaluate as *false*, `nil` and `false`. Most of the time you will not be concerned about the difference. On rare occasions you might want to have different logic for set `true`, set `false` or not set (`nil`), and only then would you test so specifically.

However, keep in mind that `0` is not a false value, so you will need to compare against that.

Taking into account the previous optimization, your `if` could be:

```
if job_and_cost_codes_found == 0
  # ...
end
```

**Don't use `then` or other bits of redundant syntax**

Most Ruby style-guides spurn useless syntax like `then`, just as they recommend avoiding `for` and instead use the Enumerable class which is far more flexible.

**Manipulate data, not strings**

You're assembling some kind of CSV-like line in the end there. Ideally you'd be using the [built-in CSV library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) to do the correct encoding, and libraries like that want data, not a string they'd have to parse.

One step closer to that is this:

```
line = [
  linenum,
  id,
  nil,
  "Employees default job and cost code do not exist in timberline. job:#{job} cost code:#{clean_cost_code}"
].join(',')

add_to_exception_output_file(line)
```

You'd presumably replace `join(',')` with the proper CSV encoding method that applies here. The library is more efficient when you can compile all of the data ahead of time into an array-of-arrays, so I'd recommend doing that if this is the end goal.

For example:

```
lines = [ ]

# ...

if (...)
  # Append an array to the lines to write to the CSV file.
  lines << [ ... ]
end
```

Keep your data in a standard structure like an Array, a Hash, or a custom object, until you're prepared to commit it to its final formatted or encoded form. That way you can perform additional operations on it if you need to do things like filtering.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to refactor this when I'm not exactly sure what it's supposed to be doing, but assuming that you want to log an error when there's no entry matching a job & code pair, here's what I've come up with:

```
def fetch_by_job_and_cost_code(job, cost_code)
  timberline_db['SELECT Job, Cost_Code FROM [JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE] WHERE [Job] = ? AND [Cost_Code] = ?', job, cost_code]
end

if fetch_by_job_and_cost_code(job, clean_cost_code).none?
  add_to_exception_output_file "#{linenum},#{id},,Employees default job and cost code do not exist in timberline. job:#{job} cost code:#{clean_cost_code}"
end
```